# Scrapy crawl in order of parents and children

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a `scrapy` crawler that parses requesting in the following order

```py
#start_requests --> crawls archive links /archive/date1, /archive/date2, ...)
#parse_archive --> archive pages (/archive/date1?p1,  /archive/date1?p2, ...)
#parse articles --> parse article (/article/{article in date1}, ...)

def start_requests(self):
   dates = [date1, date2, ...]
   for date in dates:
       yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_archive, priority=1)
    
def parse_archive(self):
    ## find number of pages if its first page
    if first_page:
        for page in pages:
            url = base_url + f'?p={page}'
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_archive, priority=2)
        
    links = function_that_find_links_in_archive_page()
    for link in links():
        yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_artcile, priority=3)
```

I tried to work priority to achieve the following request order:

```
- crawl date1
- crawl date1?p=2, crawl date1?p=3
- crawl articles in date1
then 
- crawl date2
- crawl date2?p=2, crawl date2?p=3
- crawl articles in date2
```

and so on.
but when I log the process it's like this.

```
- date1
- date2
- date3
.
.
. 
- date_n
- date1?p=2
- date2?p=2
- date1?p=3
- date1?p=3
.
.
.
date_n?p=m
- articles in date1
```

is there any way to achieve that order by playing with priority or changing the yielding algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

If you notice, the idea of priority does not work because the requests `data1, date2, date3, ..., dateN` will all have the same priority so they will be executed together. What you could do is give a whole series of requests the same priority:

```
date1 => priority 1
date1? p = 2 and date1? p = 3 => priority 1
articles in date1 => priority 1

date2 => priority 2
date2? p = 2 and date2? p = 3 => priority 2
articles in date2 => priority 2
```

In code it would be something like this:

```
def start_requests(self):
   dates = [date1, date2, ...]
   for date in dates:
       yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_archive, priority=i)
    
def parse_archive(self):
    ## find number of pages if its first page
    if first_page:
        for page in pages:
            url = base_url + f'?p={page}'
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_archive, priority=i)
        
    links = function_that_find_links_in_archive_page()
    for link in links():
        yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_artcile, priority=i)
```

About `yield`, you can check https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html to better understand how it works in conjunction with the scheduler.